# Android - permission declared in manifest not working

Tags: android, permissions

I have one question about run time permission. Even though I declared a permission in AndroidManifest.xml file, I still don't get the permission, and it gives an error of Permission denied to me. Therefore, I inserted this code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
```

After this code, i finally get the permission.

However, why can't I get the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission through declaring inside AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an android device with android 6+ you need to get permission in run time not in manifest but you have to add it in manifest too for older devices